# Mongodb multiple conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

New to MongoDB and express interactions. I'm trying to query the database based on URL parameters, essentially I want to grab URL parameters then add them to an object if they exist to use when querying the database. I set up my express path and understand that the find() method accepts an object, when I hard code the key-value pair like below I get the correct data but when I set an object called filter with the same key-value pairs as the hard-coded example and uncomment filter and comment state and type then pass it to the find method I get an empty array. Whats the reason for this and what's the best way to achieve this?

```
    app.get('/query', function (req, res) {

    var filter = {

        state: "florida",
        type: "red"
    }

    db.collection('tickets').find({ 
            //filter
            state:"florida",
            type:"red"

        })
        .toArray(function (err, documents) {
            // Here is where we decide what to do with the query results
            if (err) 
                throw err
            res.send(documents)

        })
});
```

Comment: Because you typed in `find({ filter },...)` instead of `find(filter, ... )` I presume. Seems to be a common "cargo cult" of ES6 syntax without actually understand what it means. So don't type in the brackets `{}` when you are passing in an external object. The second example. If you type in the 'first' way, that gets expanded to `{ "filter": filter }`, which of course you don't want.

Comment: Ahh I see!! the filter is already the object so I just need to pass it to the find() which accepts an object, silly me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `find` method accepts a query object as the first parameter, the query object is your `filter` object yourself. therefore, you should do it like this:

```
db.collection('tickets').find(filter)
            .toArray(function (err, documents) {
                // Here is where we decide what to do with the query results
                if (err) 
                    throw err
                res.send(documents)

            })
```